# What a bandleader should do? [ROCK BAND]

Tags: band

I am wondering what is the role of a rock band leader ? What are limits ?

Is it his role to bring rules ? Make the objectif and say : if you're not happy, leave the band ?

Comment: I think this is a very interesting and serious question (+1) the down votes may be as it was not telling what band OP was meaning ...

Comment: Every band is different. There can be no one answer to this question.

Comment: There is no specific answer to be given for this question. There can be different answers.

Answer (score 3):

Rock bands don't typically have leaders in the way that classic orchestras/ensembles do.

Rock bands can have a manager/managers, who organise the administration side of things and triage tasks away from the band members (amongst other things).

Some bands might have overbearing members who assert themselves as leaders and almost lead the band as a dictatorship (see someone like Axl Rose in the original Guns N Roses days for a good example if you're interested) but this is not a defined role, nor does one have to exist.

The internal culture and atmosphere of typical rock bands should be one of "everyone is equal". Sure, there might be exceptions where someone gets self-important and tries to boss people about, but that is typically something you should try to avoid if you want a healthy band relationship. Big Egos Break Bands.

Comment: Case in point - Ginger Baker. If he's not happy, he punches someone… anyone. [Google "ginger baker angry" for many refs ;)

Comment: A decent band should always have a leader. It's a nice idea to have a democracy, but it doesn't work in the real world. After all, someone has to fire the drummer...

Comment: @PeteCon I guess so, in the same way that a group of friends who get together regularly might have one or two people who make more of the decisions or have more prominent personalities. IRL, I don't think the leader's role should be to say "if you're not happy, leave the band" though as OP suggests...

Comment: @JamesWhiteley In my experience of playing in bands semi-professionally for a long (long!) time, saying "if you're not happy, leave the band" is exactly one of the leaders jobs, as well as organizing subs, clients, gigs, set lists, rehearsals, transport... a lot of the things that a manager would do if we were busy enough to warrant one. In a band, you're with those people for more time than anyone else apart from (maybe) your spouse - so anyone who isn't happy, isn't going to be a good fit.

Comment: @PeteCon makes sense. I guess I read it in a kind of authoritarian "my way or the highway" voice. In my experience having someone to do that kind of administrative work is healthy, but as soon as someone asserts themselves as the leader and stops consulting the rest of the band for decisions, that's when the band falls apart. Maybe I'm lucky and tasks are usually delegated out or people volunteer to do those kinds of jobs in bands I've been in. At the very least, while people might take the lead on specific tasks there hasn't been a set-in-stone permanent leader.

Comment: We were 18, 15, 14 and 13 years. Each of us was speaking of "my band". We tried to live together in a democracy but finally we decided to throw out the drummer (13) as he came always too late to the band practice or forgot it, or he forgot his sticks, or he missed the timing. Well, at least this was a great chance for him: He has been the drummer for about 20 years in one of the most famous bands of our nation :)

Comment: Having been in all kinds of situations like these, it all depends. A lot. Democracies are great in theory, but so much time can get wasted 'discussing' all sorts, from which numbers, to which gigs, which rehearsals etc. Having a designated leader is great when potential problems occur - "See Jim, he's our bandleader." But Jim has to be a special sort of person, who knows his stuff, will stand up and be counted, and is a responsible guy. I won't be told what to do by someone I have no faith in, musically particularly, whereas if someone really knows their stuff, I'll sit down and shut up!

Comment: @Tetsujin - sadly, maybe not for the victims, GB isn't punching anyone any more. RIP.

Comment: Then there's   [someone famous] And the E-Street Band.  No doubt who was in control.

Comment: @PeteCon All those jobs that you've seen a band leader do, I've seen done by various members of the band at various times. In my experience, some bands have multiple leaders, one leads on booking, one leads on writing, one leads on business matters, etc. I've definitely seen leaders who were never called leaders with no discussion of who is the leader but there is one anyway,. It just depends. IMHO this question does not have one objective answer. I was in a three-piece that had no clear leader and was essentially a democracy, but three is a much easier number to manage.

Answer (score 2):

I would discuss and define the rules before I enter in a band. The rules can be  defined by all members  - like we know from a democracy-institution, they should be  accepted and respected like  a couple living in a married  couple-ship. (Do you call this The commitment?)

The role of leadership can also be discussed:

The leader role can change

- each session (like in a meeting or conference)
- each season
- depending of the piece (may be the lead-singer or the composer)

but once chosen by the other group members the bandleader can define his own style of leadership like in a company.

It is advantageous to be so good that the others can't renounce on you.

Answer (score 1):

Both @Albrecht Hügli and @James Whiteley have good points in their answers.

I would say that it is very similar to classic chamber music like a string quartet. The similarity is that it is a small group where you can all be creative and discuss things. I have played a lot of chamber music of various kinds and we never "announced" a leader. Well you do agree on who sets the tempo which in a string quartet is typically the first vilolinist, so in that moment he is the leader, but there isn't usually an overall leadership, and there can be many sections in the music where someone else better set the tempo.

I have also played electric violin in a rock group and my experience is that it is a similar situation.

But it doesn't always hold water that there is no leader. You can find groups with a clear leader whether it is a rock group or a classic chamber music group. You can also find groups where there is a temporary leader, like someone has the leadership on a particular piece, but another one might lead another piece. So I guess there are no set standards that you have to follow.

In general a small group is like @Albrecht Hügli said in his answer: A kind of married couple-ship. You get very close in such a group just like in a marriage.

Answer (score 1):

If you just mean the power structure of the band then it depends. I was in a band where myself and another musician had more knowledge of booking shows, recording, promoting, writing, etc. - so we both shared duties. In another band I was playing strictly guitar and backups - I didn't make decisions that didn't involve my parts or my playing. As far as playing music - I say the drummer is the 'bandleader'.

You can choose to run your band like a dictator like Frank Zappa - but most of the time it's collaboration. Sometimes there are one or two creative 'leaders' and the rest of the band members are there to play. Sometimes the entire band is involved with every decision made. It really depends, and there has to be mutual respect.

Answer (score 1):

I'm the band member who fronts a band, owns the PA, finds the gigs, creates the sets, communicates/coordinates/negotiates/promotes on behalf of the band, and who does the administration and accounting. Regardless, we were a democracy and everyone had a say, but no clear leader. One member took a leadership role to direct musically and another had graphic arts skills. This democracy was working because it empowered people.

However eventually, this got out of hand when one band member wanted to change an agreed-to process to accomodate him. The situation went south when that member was disrespectful and I fired him. At that point, I appointed myself as the leader. Not having a leader will get the band mired in discussions and negotiation. There has to be a clear leader to break ties and arbitrate and guide the direction IMO.